# How do you pass an object from the model to the view while specifying which variable of the object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I am pretty fresh to .NET, c#, and MVC.

The issue I am having is that I have created an Employee object in my home controller under my Index():

```
public ActionResult Index(string Name, string ID, decimal? HourlyPayRate, int? HoursWorked)
    {
        var Emp = new Employee(Name, ID);

        if(Name == null || ID == null || !HourlyPayRate.HasValue || !HoursWorked.HasValue)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            return View(Emp);
        }    
    }
```

I am wanting to pass my View the Employee's Name to display as the title. Here is my current view:

```
@model Practice.Models.Employee

@{
ViewBag.Title = ;
}

<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>ASP.NET</h1>
<p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
<p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if I'm just not calling the correct thing with @model (still kinda fuzzy on how all of that works) or if I just don't understand the syntax for calling an object.

Comment: `ViewBag.Title = Model.Name;`

Comment: But not a lot else makes sense. Why are you passing values for `HourlyPayRate` and `HoursWorked` to a method when you never assign them to the model?

Comment: Am I not doing that correctly @StephenMuecke? I have a file called Employee.cs that has my constructors and my math related methods (finding how much they've been paid, etc).

Comment: Yes, but all your setting in the constructor is the `ID` and `Name` properties (your not setting the `HourlyPayRate` and `HoursWorked` properties). And an `Index()` method is typically for displaying a collection, not a single item - for that you would have a `Details(int ID)` method where you would pass the ID and get the Employee from the database.

Comment: Everything is being passed through route parameters.  Such as /home/index/Mike/1111/10/2.  So nothing is touching a database

Comment: Why would you do that? But my previous comment remains - your passing values to the controller and then not even using them.

Comment: Not to mention your routes can never work anyway - you cannot have 2 optional parameters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Razor, you can just write

```
<p>Employee is: @Model.Name</p>
..
```

Or in your case

```
ViewBag.Title = Model.Name
```

The rest looks ok to me.

Comment: So what would happen if I had multiple @model?  Or do you not have that inside of one view?

Comment: Typically not. I often construct on a orchestration layer the model that contains all data required for the view; which may consist of several database objects (e.g. an overview and a list of detail items). Like this, working in Razor syntax is super easy. Sometimes, though, I require some information to be available separately, such as error messages or multilingual labels. In these instances I use ViewData or ViewBag, set it the controller.